# React-native-sound setNumberofLoops not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm using react-native-sound package to play sound 10 times at a time in a loop
but setNumberOfLoops(10) or any positive number in it does not work, it start playing 30-40 times

And how can I convert callback to promise so that I can try other way to play sound multiple times, since the current implementation is in callback for play() method
(simply how can I use await with it)

```
export let xSound = new Sound("x.wav", Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Sound Not Loaded successfully");
    return;
  }
});

xSound.setNumberofLoops(10)
xSound.play()
```

Any alternatives for react-native-sound?
I'm using bare workflow for my react-app

Thanks in Advance ✨

Answer (score 0):

It's because every time the component re-renders `xSound.setNumberofLoops(10)` is called,
Instead of using it outside, take the code lines inside the load callback,

```
export let xSound = new Sound("x.wav", Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Sound Not Loaded successfully");
    return;
  }
  xSound.setNumberOfLoops(10)
});
```